# onChangeRoute ? React v4 react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The functions onEnter and onUpdate, does not work on react 4. I try different way to listen to this change but I start to turn in circles.
I would like to manage everything in my App component.

This function would allow me to close my Menu at each change of course. (isOpen) ==> False

Git of this project: https://github.com/marcdubois71450/Library-Exercise

I use react-router-dom, and react 4

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { scaleDown as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'
import './App.css';

import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import LandingPage from '../Landing';
import SignUpPage from '../SignUp';
import SignInPage from '../SignIn';
import PasswordForgetPage from '../PasswordForget';
import HomePage from '../Home';
import AccountPage from '../Account';
import AdminPage from '../Admin';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div>
            <Menu pageWrapId={ "page-wrap" } outerContainerId={ "outer-container" } isOpen={this.isOpen} >
                <Navigation />
             </Menu>
              <main id="page-wrap">
                <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING}  component={LandingPage} />
                <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} onEnter={this.onChangeRoute} component={SignUpPage} />
                <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} onEnter={this.onChangeRoute} component={SignInPage} />
                <Route path={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET} onEnter={this.onChangeRoute} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
                <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} onEnter={this.onChangeRoute} component={HomePage} />
                <Route path={ROUTES.ACCOUNT} onEnter={this.onChangeRoute} component={AccountPage} />
                <Route path={ROUTES.ADMIN} onEnter={this.onChangeRoute} component={AdminPage} />
              </main>
            </div>
          </Router>
      );
    }
}
```

I would like to manage everything in my App component.

Answer (score 0):

Use render instead of onEnter in React Router V4

Exemple from the doc:

```
// convenient inline rendering
<Route path="/home" render={() => <div>Home</div>}/>

// wrapping/composing
const FadingRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    <FadeIn>
      <Component {...props}/>
    </FadeIn>
  )}/>
)

<FadingRoute path="/cool" component={Something}/>
```

**[Render Function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)**